# What is the opposite of "a soft spot"?

Tags: word-request, colloquial-language, informal-language, antonyms

If one can have a soft spot for cherished things, one can have a ________ for dreaded ones.

I've thought about words like "imperviousness" or "immunity", but they sound more formal than soft spot. What word preservers the **colloquial** register of "soft spot" and is at the same time its antonym?

Comment: I think you mean to ask if such a term exists. There is no guarantee that it does.

Comment: As Jeffrey Carney said, there's no guarantee its exact opposite exists. You could use pretty much any phrase that means you don't really care for the thing (e.g. *I'm not a huge fan of X* etc).

Comment: I have a “sore spot” for the minimum comment length.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends how "opposite" you want it to be.

I'd use

> Immune to the charms of
> I've always had a soft spot for red hair on a man, but I'm immune to the charms of an ear piercing.

Or

> It does nothing for me
> I have a soft spot for a man who plays the piano, but guitar playing does nothing for me.

Those would generally be understood as you being either indifferent, or slightly negative. If you're trying to give the idea of a stronger dislike I'd say

> I've never been fond of
> I have a soft spot for hamsters, their little cheek pouches are very cute. I've never been fond of gerbils though — their tails scare me.

Answer (score 0):

*Soft spot* means susceptibility or sensitivity. An opposite might be *indifference*, or as an adjective, *indifferent*.

While I think "indifference" is a good opposite for "soft spot", the whole sentence won't hang together, because if something is dreaded, one is not indifferent to it.

Answer (score 0):

> **HAVE A SOFT SPOT for someone** [<sup>Collins Dictionary</sup>](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-have-a-soft-spot-for-someone#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20%27to%20have%20a%20soft%20spot%20for%20someone%27&text=If%20you%20have%20a%20soft,or%20like%20them%20a%20lot.)
> *If you have a soft spot for someone or something, you feel a great deal of affection for them or like them a lot*
> Ex: Terry had a soft spot for me.

> **HAVE IT IN for someone** [<sup>Cambridge Dictionary</sup>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-it-in-for-someone)
> *to be determined to criticise or harm someone*
> Ex: She’s always had it in for me.

Both usages are relatively informal. I suppose the "friendly" version metaphorically alludes to making a comfy / cosy place available for the object of one's affections. But I've no idea what "it" might originally / literally have referred to in the "unfriendly" version.

---

> *You can have a soft spot for your friends, but you can have it in for your enemies.*